# Preventing cheating in the Socially Acceptable Olympics

Tags: culture, sports

The Olympics are clearly unfair. For example: Stronger people are privileged when it comes to weightlifting and so on.

Let us redesign the Olympics and indeed all competition to allow for diversity.

To make things simpler for the moment let us not encroach on the Special Olympics or the Paralympics. Let us consider only the 'standard' Olympics as staged every four years.

**My proposal for running competitions**

We give all competitors a weighted belt that slows them down according to their natural ability.

**Question**

We still award medals to the winners (those first past the finishing line) but we make them as equal as possible.

How can we ensure that athletes don't cheat by pretending to be less able than they really are and then exercising their full potential in the actual competition?

Comment: Hi Chasly. Have you ever read the short story [Harrison Bergeron](http://www.tnellen.com/cybereng/harrison.html) by Kurt Vonnegut? it's a really good satirical piece that covers exactly the kind of equality thinking that you're describing.

Comment: If you slow everyone down to an equal speed, what's the use of a race? You could let them toss coins to determine the winner just as well.

Comment: Miguel de Cervantes had a proposition for racing: instead of weighting down the light, cut fat from the belly of the heavy until everyone is the same weight.

Comment: @ Renan - Really!? Do you have a reference to this? P.S. I read Spanish.

Comment: @Elmy - Interesting idea. The problem is that some events (like the marathon for example) would be over very quickly. Also athletes would not even have to attend the games. How can we retain the spectacle of the Olympics under your scheme?

Comment: @chaslyfromUK: I think I remember reading it too, and since the only thing of Cervantes I've read is Don Quixote, that's probably it, most likely, during Sancho's governorship. https://www.gutenberg.org/ebooks/996

Comment: @Renan: This sounds more like a proposition from [Cervantes de León](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cervantes_de_Leon).

Comment: @chaslyfromUK the second tome of Don Quixote. People play a prank on Sancho by pretending to name him a governor and have him preside over some things, including a race where that context happens.

Comment: That looks like golf to me.

Comment: I was gonna say, golf does this already.  It's called handicaps.  In this case, winning is not the goal so much as being proud of how much you're handicapped.  It turns golf from a sport (which it also is in other contexts) to a social game.

Comment: @chaslyfromUK How do you differentiate natural born ability and hard work from training?

Comment: @Shadowzee - As I understand it there are body-types that favour a particular sport and that is why people choose that sport. For example weight-lifters tend to be relatively short and squat whereas high jumpers are always tall and lanky.

Answer (score 6):

There is this almost identical situation in the short story: Harrison Bergeron, by Kurt Vonnegut. Harrison is a man with intellectual "advantage," over others, and so is given handicaps in the form of headphones which blast annoying bleeps in his ears to distract his attention. He is also given weights to make him weaker, to make his strength equal to those around him. Everyone who has an "advantage" over someone else is forced to be "equal."

It seems that in this sort of world, hiding your ability in certain areas is perfectly fine and legal, as long as you give yourself a handicap. For instance, one lady who has a good voice apologises for using her natural voice, before switching into a gruff and unattractive voice.

In other areas such as strength, I would guess that hiding your true strength would be illegal, similar to how removing your handicaps even when at home is illegal.

In such a society where being better than others at something is seen as sinful, I highly doubt that gold medals would ever be handed to a winner, if a winner is chosen at all, that is. If I remember correctly, everyone is given a medal for participation. And if you somehow managed to hide your true potential from the government, who monitors you VERY closely for handicaps you deserve, I think your win would be considered invalid, as if you had cheated by using steroids. You would also definitely be given more handicaps at the end of the race.

This aside, in such a dystopian world, unless the government has some form of omniscience, it is inevitable that there will be a large number of people who purposefully limit themselves to avoid receiving a handicap.

I hope this answers your question about what could happen if an athlete hid their true potential to avoid handicaps.

Answer (score 2):

The system you are trying to set up is already used in horse racing: it's called [handicap system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Handicap_(horse_racing)).

> In a horse handicap race (sometimes called just "handicap"), each horse must carry a specified weight called the impost, assigned by the racing secretary or steward based on factors such as past performances, so as to equalize the chances of the competitors. [...] In Britain the horses are assigned weights according to a centralised rating system maintained by the British Horseracing Authority (BHA). Weights may be increased if a horse wins a race between the publication of the weights and the running of the contest.
>
> The handicapping process can be simple or complex but usually includes the following elements prior to the race:
>
> - Study of the Daily Racing Form.
> - Observing the horses’ body language and behaviour in the paddock and/or post parade.
> - Watching the tote board for the changing odds of each horse and thus for clues about how the betting public views a horse’s chances of winning the upcoming race

Since athletes compete for the victory, you base the handicap on the result of competitions, where an athlete is less likely to sandbag its performance.

Comment: That's not the same system. It would be the same if naturally faster horses would be required to run longer distance, for example. Or carry even *more* weight. In horse racing every horse carries the same weight, not related at all to its natural advantages.

Answer (score 1):

The problem here is that I don't pretend to be less able outside the competition season, I quite literally am less able outside competition season. Training ramps up in the run-up to a major competition and eases off afterwards.

The only option is to base it on past performance of that athlete. If they choose not to train up for minor events then you're calling that cheating, but what you're wanting to measure isn't about the full current capability of a competitor, it's about their maximum possible capability and that's impossible to track.

Comment: Well I'm not saying they shouldn't train. What happens if they train optimally but in any competition where their ability is actually *assessed* they deliberately under-perform. Then when to Olympics comes round they make sure to have done just enough to qualify but not raise suspicion?

Comment: @chaslyfromUK, all you have to do is enough to qualify, you don't have to be at your peak to qualify, you have to be good enough and place well enough. The Olympics is a special case as you have to qualify for your national team rather than the event itself. If public trials lead to handicapping, then qualification will take place behind closed doors.